# How do I link to a SPA url?

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application

I have a single page Vue application that uses hash history for the URLs (i.e. https://www.myapp.com/#/sign-up). I have another website that is using Wagtail as a CMS tool that is attempting to link to my vue spa using an anchor tag but it doesn't appear to be working. The website with the anchor tag was built with a pre-made theme using jQuery.

`<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary transition-3d-hover" href="https://www.myapp.com/#/sign-up">`

I expect clicking the link will take me to my sign-up page but nothing happens, I see this on the console log when clicking the link:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/sign-up
    at Function.oe.error (jquery.min.a2530ed98bf8.js:2)
    at oe.tokenize (jquery.min.a2530ed98bf8.js:2)
    at oe.select (jquery.min.a2530ed98bf8.js:2)
    at Function.oe (jquery.min.a2530ed98bf8.js:2)
    at Function.e.find (jquery-migrate.min.05689c22f0c8.js:59)
    at w.fn.init.find (jquery.min.a2530ed98bf8.js:2)
    at e.fn.init.w.fn.init (jquery.min.a2530ed98bf8.js:2)
    at new e.fn.init (jquery-migrate.min.05689c22f0c8.js:43)
    at w (jquery.min.a2530ed98bf8.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (scroll-nav.787831ada42e.js:16)
```

Navigating to the url https://www.myapp.com/#/sign-up does work as expected, just not through clicking the link. I'm relatively new to front-end development and am lost on what could be causing the problem.

Comment: If I copy that line into a simple HTML file, open it in a web browser, and then click on it, it works. Have you got any JavaScript on your site that is reading the hrefs? Does the error only occur in Wagtail? If you remove the `#`, does it work (even if the link is incorrect)?

Comment: Ah it looks like there is jQuery being run on the site that could be causing the problem, the original error message actually comes from jQuery, I've updated my post to show the full message. Removing the # does work in terms of redirecting (though to the wrong place as you mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use hashbang navigation as it's deprecated since 2015. Instead use VueRouter to get rid of your hashbang and configure your server-side app to redirect all routes to `/`, letting Vue handling the routes.

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history'
})
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought hashbang and hash urls are not the same thing (#! vs #), Hash url is still the default behavior for vue router

Comment: It's exactly the same thing, with the same behavior. It's used as a backward compatibility feature to make sure it works out of the box. See my edit to make it work without the hash, but you need to configure your server to redirect everything to `/` first.

Answer (score 1):

I am not that clear about the question and maybe not the best person to answer, but typically you need to configure your server with a [URL Rewrite](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04) to be able to work with an SPA application, but if that was the issue you wouldn't be able to open that url directly either but you say that you can. So I am not sure what the issue is. I suggest that you take a look at [this link](https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59) also related to configuring the server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Thomas Edwards line of questioning it lead me to the answer:

The website attempting to link to my SPA indeed had some jQuery code on it for autoscrolling behavior where the function was preventing default behavior for all hashed links.